# Is there a faster way or keyboard shortcut to close files without saving in Preview?

Tags: keyboard, preview

When closing an unsaved file in Preview, you're presented with the "Do you want to keep this new document" modal:

[image: Close document modal in Preview on macOS]

There doesn't seem to be a quick way to access the Delete button besides tabbing or using the mouse. I work with a lot of quick throwaway screenshots throughout the day and this step slows me down.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this button, or another way to close files that will not show this dialog?

Comment: Simply press and hold **⌘**, then press **W** and then **Delete**. Pressing all three simultaneously (even holding them all down at once) works for me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a "Save As" window, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> to close the window and delete the unsaved file.

This essentially selects the "Delete" option from that "Save As" window.

Pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> selects the "Cancel" option. <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects "Save".

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new Automator.app Quick Action document and add a "Run AppleScript" action to your workflow.

Then you would paste this following AppleScript code into the "Run AppleScript" action.

```
tell application "Preview" to close window 1 saving no
```

You can also use this following AppleScript code, instead, if you prefer to close all of the Preview documents at the same time without any dialogs popping up

```
tell application "Preview" to close windows saving no
```

[image]

Then you could save the Automator file as "Preview Close No Save".  Once that file is saved you can now assign it a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences.  Now anytime you are using Preview app, any time you use your new assigned keyboard shortcut, it should automatically close the visible document without popping up any dialogs.

[image]

If for some reason your new keyboard shortcut does not work, it may be because it conflicts with another keyboard shortcut already assigned.  In that case try assigning it a new keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Simply press and hold **⌘**, then press **W** and then **Delete**. Pressing all three simultaneously (even holding them all down at once) works for me and negates the need to create an Automator Service/Quick Action.

Comment: Nice one… I added an additional snippet to my answer, that I don't believe any standard keyboard shortcuts would be able to handle.

Comment: @user3439894 and pkamb's answer were what I was hoping for, but this is an awesome shortcut too—I think both together will be great.

Comment: Yes, what you added, `tell application "Preview" to close windows saving no`, after I posted my comment makes much more sense for an Automator Service/Quick Action then what you originally posted. So much so, you should make it the focal point of your answer since the original only replicates what can already be done natively with **⌘W-Delete**.